# Exercise I.7.2 in Geometry and Topology by Bredon

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm working though the first chapter in *Geometry and Topology* by Glenn Bredon, and I'm stuck on Exercise I.7.2, which is related to compactness. It reads:

> Let $X$ be a compact space and let $\{C_{\alpha}\,|\,\alpha\in A\}$ be a collection of closed sets, closed with respect to finite intersections. Let $C=\bigcap C_{\alpha}$ and suppose that $C\subset U$ with $U$ open. Show that $C_{\alpha}\subset U$ for some $\alpha$.

I was thinking that if some $C_{\alpha}$ is empty, then $C$ is empty and we're done, so we can assume every $C_{\alpha}$ is nonempty. With this assumption, and the fact that the collection $\{C_{\alpha}\,|\,\alpha\in A\}$ is closed under finite intersections, we know that $C$ is then nonempty due to the "finite intersection property" characterization of compactness.

From here I was thinking of taking advantage of the fact that $\{C_{\alpha}\,|\,\alpha\in A\}$ directed set (with partial ordering given by reverse inclusion) to do something with nets, but I'm pretty much stuck at this point.

I feel like there should be an easier way. Does anyone have any hints or advice they could give? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For each $\alpha\in A$ let $U_\alpha=X\setminus C_\alpha$; then $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ is an open cover of $X\setminus U$. Since $X\setminus U$ is closed, it is also compact. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I feel kind of silly now asking it now since it's so simple. So following your logic, there exists a finite subcollection $C_{\alpha_1},C_{\alpha_{2}},\ldots C_{\alpha_{n}}$ such that
$$
\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}C\setminus C_{\alpha_{k}}\supset X\setminus U,
$$
and hence
$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}C_{\alpha_{k}}\subset U.
$$
Since the collection is closed under finite intersection, the left-hand side belongs to the collection and is the desired element?

Comment: @Blake: Exactly right.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I pressed enter without holding ctrl so I submitted my comment prematurely.

Comment: @Blake: You’re welcome! (Don’t worry about it; I suspect that everyone who posts here at all often has done it. I certainly have.)